# Web scraping more than one "brother" <div>

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape in python with selenium. The website is a sport results page, and my final goal is to get in a csv (or xml in a future) the full list of results. The website code is something like this:

```
<div class="sportName soccer">
    <div class="event__header">
        <div class="event_title">
            <div class="event_titleBox">
            <span class="event_title--type">"Country"</span>
            <span class="event_title--name">"Competition"</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event_round">Day 1</div>
    <div class="event_match">Match 1</div>
    <div class="event_match">Match 2</div>
    <div class="event_match">Match 3</div>
    <div class="event_round">Day 2</div>
    <div class="event_match">Match 1</div>
    <div class="event_match">Match 2</div>
    <div class="event_match">Match 3</div>
</div>
```

It shows up like this:

```
Country Competition
Day 1
Match 1
Match 2
Match 3
Day 2
Match 1
Match 2
Match 3
```

My problem is when I try to get the info, I'm unable to get the whole information in the same variable, I'm using

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='sportName soccer']//*[@class='event__header']")
```

And this gets all the info but all in one single line. How can I get both "event_titleBox", "event_round" and "event_match scraped in order, in the same variable?

I can do by scraping the classes one each in a single variant, but then I get all the info messy and I don't know how to put in the correct order after that...

There is a way to pick up more than one class in the find_elements_by_xpath?

Many thanks

Comment: try this `results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'event_titleBox') or contains(@class, 'event_round') or contains(@class, 'event_match')]")`
Just combine classes

Comment: worked! many thanks!

what's difference in @class='abc' and contains(@class, 'abc')?

Comment: `@class='abc'` - it's mean that class should be equal ``abc``,
`contains(@class, 'abc')` - it's mean that class should contains part `abc`.

From your example, following path also will work

`//*[@class='event_titleBox' or @class='event_round' or @class='event_match']`

Comment: Thanks! And last question. Could be the possibility, once I get the variable with all the information in sepparate lines, to group one inside others? I mean getting "event_match" inside "event_rounde, for instance

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Could you please provide example of result, what you need to get

Answer (score 0):

In general it's better and cleaner to use css:

```
.soccer .event__header ~ div
```